# how to install geoplot on google colab

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science, google-colaboratory, geoplot

How can we install geoplot in google colab?

```
!pip install geoplot
```

The above gives

```
Collecting geoplot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/8f/46133752e1f02e70501939e739b81cbc85c79d7398c963b8a25a3178bffe/geoplot-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: mapclassify>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from geoplot) (2.4.2)
```

But when I try to import geoplot the package is unrecognised

Answer (score 1):

I think they don't recommend using `pip install geoplot` here is a [link](https://github.com/ResidentMario/geoplot/blob/master/docs/installation.rst) to their documentation hope it helps you can use `conda` though.

Comment: Actually neither methods work on google colab.

Comment: did you try with `conda` colab doesn't support `conda` by default you gotta use anaconda.

Comment: Yes, I have tried anaconda too instead of conda. It wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Cartopy is required for geoplot. You need to use `apt` to install it. Then, you can install geoplot with `pip` normally.

```
!apt install python3-cartopy
!pip install geoplot
```

Here's an example [colab notebook](https://colab.to/105PYYOTGrKxTmG6KzJdTwm7hTSVq8eYh)

Comment: I don't know about geoplot but would you mind telling the difference between `pip install pkg` and `!pip install pkg` as both of these give same results in my case

Comment: Colab use auto-magic. So `pip` becomes `%pip` automatically. But `!pip` which call command line is more explicit. Both methods wok, but if you use just `pip`, you cannot have the second line, you must have just 1-line cell.